# What does the \? (backslash question mark) escape sequence mean?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, escaping

I'm writing a regular expression in Objective-C.

The escape sequence `\w` is illegal and emits a warning, so the regular expression `/\w/` must be written as `@"\\w"`; the escape sequence `\?` is [valid, apparently,](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2010/09/14/escape-sequences/) and doesn't emit a warning, so the regular expression `/\?/` must be written as `@"\\?"` (i.e., the backslash must be escaped).

Question marks aren't invisible like `\t` or `\n`, so why is `\?` a valid escape sequence?

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm not asking about the quantifier, I'm asking about a string escape sequence. That is, this doesn't emit a warning:

```
NSString *valid = @"\?";
```

By contrast, this *does* emit a warning ("Unknown escape sequence '\w'"):

```
NSString *invalid = @"\w";
```

Comment: It means you're trying to match (depending on the function) a literal `?`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "\?" an escape sequence in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374878/why-is-an-escape-sequence-in-c-c) (Objective-C inherits this feature from C, so this is actually a duplicate.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It specifies a literal question mark. It is needed because of a little-known feature called [trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs), where you can write a three-character sequence starting with question marks to substitute another character. If you have trigraphs enabled, in order to write "??" in a string, you need to write it as `"?\?"` in order to prevent the preprocessor from trying to read it as the beginning of a trigraph.

(If you're wondering "Why would anybody introduce a feature like this?": Some keyboards or character sets didn't include commonly used symbols like `{`. so they introduced trigraphs so you could write `??<` instead.)

Comment: Good answer! Thanks for the historical context too.

Comment: but, really, it's useless in string literals. You can write any symbol using a hexadecimal value `"\x3f"`

Answer (score -1):

`?` in regex is a quantifier, it means 0 or 1 occurences. When appended to the `+` or `*` quantifiers, it makes it "lazy".

For example, applying the regex `o?` to the string `foo?` would match `o`.

However, the regex `o\?` in `foo?` would match `o?`, because it is searching for a literal question mark in the string, instead of an arbitrary quantifier.

Applying the regex `o*?` to `foo?` would match `oo`.

More info on quantifiers [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).